# R function keeps return NULL

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to implement Ridge regression using R. But after making sure every function works well, when I finally tries to visualize the result. The function `myRidge()` keeps returning `NULL`.

I am not very familiar with R and I think I might make some fundamental mistake and makes `myRidge()` mistakenly returns `NULL`.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(file="./sweep.cpp")

myRidge <- function(X, Y, lambda, use_QR = FALSE, use_C = TRUE){

  n <- dim(X)[1]
  p <- dim(X)[2]

  Z <- cbind(rep(1, n), X, Y)
  A <- t(Z) %*% Z

  D <- diag(rep(lambda, p + 2))
  D[p + 2, p + 2] <- 0

  D[1, 1] <- 0

  A <- A + D
  S <- mySweepC(A, p + 1)

  beta_ridge <- S[1:(p + 1), p + 2]

  return(beta_ridge)
}

n <- 50
p <- 200
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow=n)
beta_true <- matrix(rep(0, p), nrow=p)
beta_true[1:5] <- seq(5) # 1, 2,..., 5
# add noise with mu = 1
Y <- 1 + X %*% beta_true + rnorm(n)
# regularization
lambda_all <- 10 ^ seq(-3, 3)

# solve for beta for different regularization
beta_est <- matrix(rep(0, p), nrow=p)
Y_hat <- matrix(rep(0, length(lambda_all)*n), nrow=n)
for(i in 1:length(lambda_all)){
    beta_est <- myRidge(X, Y, lambda_all[i])
    Y_hat[,i] <- X %*% beta_est
}
# visualization
estimation_error <- rep(0, length(lambda_all))
for (i in 1:length(lambda_all)){
  estimation_error[i] <- sum((Y-Y_hat[,i])^2)
}
matplot(t(matrix(rep(1,p+1),nrow=1)%*%abs(beta_all)), t(beta_all), type = 'l')
matplot(estimation_error,type = 'l')
```

where I use `Rcpp` to implement `mySweepC()`.

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export()]]
mat mySweepC(const mat A, int m){
  mat B = A;
  int n = B.n_rows;

  for(int k = 0; k < m; k++){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if((i != k) & (j != k))
          B(i, j) = B(i, j) - B(i, k) * B(k, j) / B(k, k);
      }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(i != k)
        B(i, k) = B(i, k) / B(k, k);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
      if(j != k)
        B(k, j) = B(k, j) / B(k, k);
    }

    B(k, k) = - 1 / B(k, k);

  }

  return(B);
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined `myRidge()` anywhere in this example

Comment: @dmca I thought it was because of some other reasons (irrelevant of `myRidge()`), I have posted the entire code.

Comment: Add some `print` statements in the function body (or use `browser`/breakpoints in RStudio) to check intermediate results. Basically, do some debugging.

Comment: @Roland Already done that before posting the question. I believe there is something subtle (at least for me) happen and that's why I ask for help here.

Comment: I don't get `NULL` but `Error in X %*% beta_est : non-conformable arguments`.

Comment: @Roland this is exactly because the returned value is `NULL`

Comment: No, its not. `beta_est` is a numeric vector of length 201 whereas `X` has 200 columns.

Comment: @Roland you are right but I found that this was not the bug that caused the error. It turns out that in slicing `beta_ridge <- S[1:(p+1), p+2]`, I need to instead use `beta_ridge <- S[1:(p+1), p+2, drop=FALSE]`.